# how to test if a variable is valid or whether it is initialized or not in C?

Tags: c, variables, data-structures, initialization, cs50

I am learning C from scratch with Harvard's cs50 course.
I've been given an array that's been initialized this way:

```c
int stuff[9][9];
```

now I have to handle it.
I want to check if each item of the array exists: if not, make `stuff[i][j] = 0`, otherwise, `stuff[i][j]++`
But I am searching without resulting on how to check if the variable I am manipulating exists or is valid or whatever: there is no `!!stuff[i][j]`, nor some `typeof stuff[i][j]` or comparing `if (stuff[i][j] == 'undefined')` or `NULL` or any variations of that which I can use...
So, how can I check if a declared variable has not yet been initialized?

---

**update**
I've made a test with this:

```
int a[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    a[i] = a[i] || 0;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("a[%i] -> %i\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

so, if `a[i]` didn't exist (i.e. had no value assigned to it), it would receive value `0`.
this was the output of the `printf`:

```
a[0] -> 1
a[1] -> 1
a[2] -> 0
```

That's good because this approach didn't throw an error, but... what are those numbers??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the above array is a local variable and not a global, the values of the array are *uninitialized* and in fact you *can't* check whether a variable is uninitialized or not, as simply attempting to read such a variable can trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It sounds like you want all array elements to start with the value 0.  The simplest way to do this is to initialize the array as such:

```
int stuff[9][9] = {{ 0 }};
```

Which explicitly sets element `[0][0]` to 0 and implicitly sets all other elements to 0.

Alternately, you can create a loop to set all values to 0 to start before doing your "regular" processing.

Comment: Good to know that... but assuming this is a global variable, is there a workaround?

Comment: If it's a global and not explicitly initialized, then it's implicitly initialized to all values 0.

Comment: actually, you're right... my mistake was in another part of the code kkk.  
But I learned with your previous answer how to make all items initialize to the same value.

Comment: @AtauãDoederlein — In current versions of C, you can only make all items zero (or explicitly list some items as non-zero, leaving everything else as zero).  GCC has an extension that allows you to repeat non-zero initializers, but it isn't standard.